# Как убрать синий фон при клике

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

При клике примерно на 0.5 секунды появляется синий фон, стрелка сделана с использованием ссылки в которой svg картинка.
Но та же проблема при клике на div. Возможно это проблема из-за анимации.
Появляется только на мобильных устройствах
Подключен wow.js, animate.css

[image: Проблема]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Добавьте к вашему елементу `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: Спасибо, сработало

Comment: Спасибо, помогло:)))